# Java - Hashmapping a text file

Tags: java, hashmap

and please excuse my ignorance, I have been puzzling on this for a while.

I have a huge .txt file containing mostly letters. I need to create HashMaps to store word length, Word characters and Word count...i have to print out the longest word occurred more than three times and show how many times it occurred. 
Im thinking something like that

```
private void readWords(){ 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"));

Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>
}
```

The problem is that i dont quite know how to save to HashMap, can anybody help please?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you gone through the [`HashMap` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)?

Comment: can you be more clear about "i dont quite know how to save to HashMap"?

Comment: You're going to need to parse the file somehow. Perhaps a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HashMapExample {

static String fileName = "text.txt";
private static Scanner input;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String word = input.next();
        if (map.containsKey(word)) {
            int temp = map.get(word) + 1;
            map.put(word, temp);
        } else {
            map.put(word, 1);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("printing longest word(s) with word count < 3");
    System.out.println("");

    // iterate through the key set and display word, word length and values
    System.out.printf("%-25s\t%-25s\t%s\n", "Word", "Word Length", "Count");

    String longest = getLongest(map);

    int valueOfLongest = 0;
    if (!longest.equals("")) {
        valueOfLongest = longest.length();
        System.out.printf("%-25s\t%-25s\t%s\n", longest, longest.length(), map.get(longest));
        map.remove(longest);
    }


    boolean isAllRemoved = false;
    while (!isAllRemoved) {
        isAllRemoved = false;
        longest = getLongest(map);
        if (!longest.equals("") && longest.length() == valueOfLongest){
            System.out.printf("%-25s\t%-25s\t%s\n", longest, longest.length(), map.get(longest));
            map.remove(longest);
        } else
            isAllRemoved = true;
    }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("printing next longest word(s) with word count > = 3");
    System.out.println("");

    // iterate through the key set and display word, word length and values
    System.out.printf("%-25s\t%-25s\t%s\n", "Word", "Word Length", "Count");

    String nextLongest = getNextLongest(map, valueOfLongest);

    int valueOfNextLongest = 0;
    if (!longest.equals("")) {
        valueOfNextLongest = nextLongest.length();
        System.out.printf("%-25s\t%-25s\t%s\n", nextLongest, nextLongest.length(), map.get(nextLongest));
        map.remove(nextLongest);
    }

    boolean isNextLongest = false;
    while (!isNextLongest) {
        isNextLongest = true;
        nextLongest = getNextLongest(map, valueOfLongest);
        if (!(nextLongest.equals("")) && nextLongest.length() ==  valueOfNextLongest) {
            System.out.printf("%-25s\t%-25s\t%s\n", nextLongest, nextLongest.length(), map.get(nextLongest));
            map.remove(nextLongest);
            isNextLongest = false;
        }

    }

}

public static String getLongest(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    String longest = "";
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = (String) entry.getKey();
        if (longest.length() < key.length() && map.get(key) < 3) {
            longest = key;
        }

    }

    return longest;
}

public static String getNextLongest(Map<String, Integer> map,
        int valueOfLongest) {
    String nextLongest = "";
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = (String) entry.getKey();
        if (valueOfLongest > key.length() && nextLongest.length() < key.length() && map.get(key) >= 3) {
            nextLongest = key;
        }

    }

    return nextLongest;
}
}
```

Comment: If the longest word is occurred <3 times, it will not be printed but the next longest word that occurrs >=3 will be printed. BTW that code is brilliant! It needs some tweaking tho - any non-letter characters should not be considered into the length of the word

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import com.google.common.collect.HashMultiset;
import com.google.common.collect.Multiset;

public class CountWord {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("c:/a.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        // init the longest size 0
        int longestSize = 0;
        String s = null;
        // may be some word have the same length
        Set<String> finalAnswerSet = new HashSet<String>();
        Multiset<String> everyWordSet = HashMultiset.create();
        while (br != null && (s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // put every word into the everyWordSet
            everyWordSet.add(s);
            // we care about the word appear 3+ times
            if (everyWordSet.count(s) > 3) {
                if (s.length() > longestSize) {
                    //if s'length is the longest,clear the finalAnswerSet and put s into it
                    longestSize = s.length();
                    finalAnswerSet.clear();
                    finalAnswerSet.add(s);
                } else if (s.length() == longestSize) {
                    // finalAnswerSet may contains multi values
                    finalAnswerSet.add(s);
                }
            }
        }
        // and now we have the longestSize,and finalAnswerSet contains the answers,let's check it
        System.out.println("The longest size is:" + longestSize);
        for (String answer : finalAnswerSet) {
            System.out.println("The word is :" + answer);
            System.out.println("The word appears time is:" + everyWordSet.count(answer));
        }
        //don't forget to close the resource
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You got the point right but as of now, the programm includes ALL characters, which it should not. !")(/#?%=)¤   etc should be excluded as well as anything else than LETTERS.

Comment: A simple solution is that you put a regular expression at the begining of the Big WHILE,you can filter any characters you want,but the performance will be week.Or you can use apache's WordUtils,the method isAlphanumeric will jundge if the word is alpha,numeric or not.But!The filter rule depends on yourself,so does the file's format,the code[br.readLine] is just an assumption.I think u can resolve it,good luck!